# Validate only a part of XML file using an XSD file

Tags: c, xml, xsd

Is there a way to validate only a part of XML file using XSD file and ignore the other contents of the XML file. I want to validate only a couple of tags in XML file using XSD file. My XML file contains many tags, but xsd contains elements for only few of the tags.

Is it possible to attain this somehow?

Comment: For certain cases you can use `<xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>` in your XSD: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_any.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways (at least) to achieve this, in principle.

First, you can in principle tell the validator which elements in the document you want to validate; the XSD spec does not require validation to start at the document root.  In practice, command-line validators almost never provide run-time options for starting validation anywhere but the root. I think validation libraries are more likely to provide that functionality; they often (or at least sometimes) provide functions to allow you to pass in the element at which validation should start, together with the necessary schema information.

If your validator doesn't allow you to validate selectively, you can write a schema that contains declarations for just those elements and attributes you want to validate, and invoke a validator on the document root in "lax validation mode" -- which means, essentially "If you find in the schema a declaration for an element in the document, then validate the element against its declaration, otherwise accept it (pretend it matches a lax wildcard in the declaration of its parent) and move on." The validator will thus ignore elements for which you provide no declarations and validate elements for which you do provide declarations.  (Note that conforming XSD processors are not required to provide lax-validation mode, and the definition of lax validation in the spec is a little underspecified, but I believe most available processors do support it and do the same thing in lax mode.)

Comment: Hi there, i am still stuck with this issue. Not able to find a solution yet. Here's the part of my xml that I need to verify:-

`<telegram data-set-id="1122" com-parameter-id="1" com-id="101">               
<pd-send-parameter cycle-time="500" destination-uri="grpTCMS.aCar.lCst" redundant="1"/>
</telegram>`

Please note : the rest of the xml keeps varying.

Answer (score 0):

An **ugly hack** would be to construct a "validatable" document from the main one by omitting that which you don't want validated, and validate that one. I don't endorse this approach, but it's an answer at least.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this in practice is probably to do the validation using the validate expression in XQuery (or copy-of with validation in XSLT). This allows you to select the element you want to validate, and perform the validation, in one go.

The downside might be that validate in XQuery is defined to be a fatal error if the document is invalid, so the implementation might simply stop on the first error rather than focusing on giving you as much information about the invalidity as it can. At this stage you need to find out how it's implemented in a particular processor and/or how to configure that processor.